# How to pass callback method as parameter in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I will explain the need based on below example

This is the method that need to be called after an async operation

```
    -(void) myCallbackMethodOne: (NSString *)response
    {
        //method to be called
    }

    -(void) myCallbackMethodTwo: (NSString *)response
    {
        //method to be called
    }



    -(void) getDataFromServerWithCallback: (NSString *)requestString _Callback(CallbackMethod *) methodName
    {
        //logic to send request and 
        //to set callback method something similar to
        [setCallbackMethod  methodName]; 
    }

    -(void) onDataRecievedFromServerWithResponse: (NSString *) response //this method gets called as part of framework
    {
        [callTheCallbackMethod: response]; 
    }
```

A place to call the method to demonstrate the requirement

```
    -int main()
    {
        [getDataFromFromServerWithCallback: @"getTopNews" _Callback:myCallbackMethodOne];  //this is the requirement; I should be able to pass myCallbackMethod as argument

        [getDataFromFromServerWithCallback: @"getBusinessNews" _Callback:myCallbackMethodTwo];  //this is the requirement; I should be able to pass myCallbackMethod as argument

    }
```

Comment: This pattern is covered by delegates or blocks in Objective-C.

Comment: Here is an example from my own code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.m

Comment: -1 for not having researched properly.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am not sure about that. To add some more clarity. 'mycallbackmethod' and 'main' method is written by the developer writing ios application. Developer is calling a library method 'getDataFromServerWithCallback' with his callback method as argument. Library developer should handle it to call the callback method, whatever be the methodname passed. ie Method name is dynamic for library, ie it could be 'topNewsHandler' or 'businessNewsHandler'

Comment: And the library is also Objective-C?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, library handles the part of sending request. And also after getting the response, it should call the method developer wants to be executed

Comment: @chris_sencha it is called delegate or block.

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani For delgate, library should already have defined that particular delgate, right? But here library doesn't knows which method to be called before hand. Library gets it as argument

Answer (score 1):

There are two well established patterns for this type of functionality:

1) Delegate:

```
@protocol ResponseDelegate
- (void)handleResponse:(NSString *)response;
@end

@interface CommsClass : NSObject
@property (weak) id<ResponseDelegate> delegate;
- (void)sendRequest:(NSString *)request;
@end

@interface CallingClass : NSObject <ResponseDelegate>
{
    CommsClass _commsClass;
}

- (void)callingCode;
@end

@interface CallingCode

- (void)callingCode
{
    _commsClass = [CommsClass new];
    _commsClass.delegate = self;
    [_commsClass sendRequest:@"Blah"];
}

- (void)handleResponse:(NSString *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Whoot: %@", response);
}

@end
```

2) Blocks.

```
typedef (^HandleResponseBlock)(NSString *response);

@interface CommsClass : NSObject
- (void)sendRequest:(NSString *)request
withCompletionBlock:(HandleResponseBlock)block;
@end
```

Comment: I had already implemented the delegate way you mentioned. But here the response is always wired to the method 'handleResponse'. What I am looking for is a way to pass this method name as argument and then invoke it.

Comment: Yes. Right now the handleResponse version of my code is as below \n -(void)responseCallback:(NSString *)operationName _String:(NSString *)response
{
       
    if ([((NSObject*)operationName) equals: ((NSObject*)@"getNews") ])
    {
       [self callNewsHandler: operationName _String:response];
    }else if ([((NSObject*)operationName) equals: ((NSObject*)@"getRates") ])
    {
        [self callRatesHandler: operationName _String:response];
    }    
}

Comment: I wanted callNewsHandler and callRatesHandler to be called directly. But that should not be wired. Method name could be anything as the application developer wish

Answer (score 0):

For objective C, I believe you have to pass the callback using block. But for Swift, since methods are also first class citizens, we can do something like this:

```
func buttonDidTapped(sender: AnyObject!) {
    doSomethingWithCallback(callbackFunc: myCallback)
}

func doSomethingWithCallback(callbackFunc: (NSDictionary)->()) {
    //do something
    callbackFunc(["param": "pass any param by dynamic dictionary"])
}


func myCallback(infoDict: NSDictionary) {
    //callback implementation
}
```

We can define the callback and as any functions and pass it like any parameters.

For more information on using objective-c and swift in the same project, please refer to Apple document:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html

Hope that it helps.

Comment: The questioner didn't ask for an answer in Swift it's tagged specifically for Objective-C.

Comment: Yes, I am not using Swift. Need the implementation for objective c

Answer (score 0):

I got my requirement working by using selectors

```
-(void) myCallbackMethodOne: (NSString *)response

{

    //method to be called

}


-(void) myCallbackMethodTwo: (NSString *)response
{
    //method to be called
}



-(void) getDataFromServerWithCallback: (NSString *)requestString _Callback:(SEL) methodName _Caller(id):callingClass
{
    //write the logic here to store methodname and caller to reference variables
    //so that it will be accessible in onDataRecievedFromServerWithResponse
    //and to send the request

}

-(void) onDataRecievedFromServerWithResponse: (NSString *) response //this method gets called as part of framework
{
    [callingClass performSelector:methodName withObject:response];
}


 -int main()
{

    SEL methodOneSelctor =@selector(myCallbackMethodOne:);
    [getDataFromFromServerWithCallback: @"getTopNews" _Callback:methodOneSelctor _MethodCaller:self];  //I should be able to pass myCallbackMethod as argument

    SEL methodTwoSelctor =@selector(myCallbackMethodTwo:);
   [getDataFromFromServerWithCallback: @"getBusinessNews" _Callback:methodTwoSelctor _MethodCaller:self];  //I should be able to pass myCallbackMethod as argument

}
```